# Shared memory alignment in C++

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

Is there any alignment for allocated shared memory? If yes, is it for all operating system?

For example, allocating shared memory in boost:

```
boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object* segment =
    new boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object(
        boost::interprocess::create_only,
        "name",
        boost::interprocess::read_write);

segment->truncate(10000);
```

Comment: No, and no. In the 1400 pages that make up the current C++ standard, there is not mention of anything called "shared memory". This is an operating system-specific resource and, as such, the particular details of shared memory is specific to each operating system.

Comment: It's probably reasonable to assume that general-purpose allocators like that one return memory at the fundamental alignment (i.e. `alignof(std::max_align_t)`, so it should work for "normal" types.)

Answer (score 1):

The shared/virtual memory system allocates and maps memory pages and is aligned by the page size. See a list of pages sizes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)#Huge_pages). Page size is CPU and OS specific. I am not aware of modern CPUs that use page sizes smaller than 4kB.

On a POSIX system you can find out the page size using `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`. In case when huge pages are in use, this call returns the smallest page size.

Comment: There is also a function in std that takes unaligned memory and returns an aligned pointer into it.  It requires extra space of aligment-1.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shred memory in C++ itself.  There are various extensions.  The raw ones return page aligned blocks, but your wrapper might add a sub-block allocation system to them.

If you have a block of memory you can find an aligned pointer within the block, either manually by messing with bits (non portable), or using [`std::align`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align).  It is designed to make it pretty easy to "peel" off aligned sub blocks from an unaligned block.

```
struct aligned_peeler {
  void* raw=nullptr;
  std::size_t size=0;
  void* operator*( std::size_t align, std::size_t amt ){
    return std::align(align, amt, raw, size);
  }
};
```

Now an `aligned_peeler` can be handed a block, and you can ask for aligned pieces from it.  It will fail and return nullptr when it runs out of room.

Turning this into a real free store is a lot of work, but I'd guess `boost` has at least one allocator that can be fed shared memory pages as a source.